# When the first letter is put in the input field the submit button should pop up

Tags: jquery, html, input, popup

I am making form where I want to pop-up the submit button when the user enters the first letter.

**Javascript Section**:

```
$('#cams_email').blur(function()
 {
    if(!$('cams_email').val())
    {
        $('#cams_submit').hide();
    }
    else
        $('#cams_submit').show();;
});
```

**HTML Section**:

```
<div class="form-row form-group" id="cams_section" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-md-5">
    <h5>Email ID<span class="form-required">*</span></h5>
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-7" id="cams_e">
    <input type="email" name="cams_email" id="cams_email" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="cams_submit" style="display: none;">Submit Cams Data</button>
```

Comment: You forgot to start with "#" on selector here `$('cams_email').val()`

Comment: Why is there display: none on the form? User won't have any way of entering the first letter

Comment: Use ` .on('keyup',function(){});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd better use jQuery [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) in this situation where the condition checks for an empty value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#cams_email').on('blur keyup',function(){
$('#cams_submit').toggle($(this).val()!='');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row form-group" id="cams_section">
                            <label class="col-md-5">
                                <h5>Email ID<span class="form-required">*</span></h5>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-7" id="cams_e">
                                <input type="email" name="cams_email" id="cams_email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="cams_submit" style="display: none;">Submit Cams Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the working example in the snippet below. 
You add a `keyup` event to your input, and when the event is triggered, you check if something was written (when `.val()` isn't empty), and if that is the case, you remove `display: none` from the submit button.

```js
$("#cams_email").on("keyup", function(){
 if(!($(this).val() === '')){
     $("#cams_submit").css("display", "block");
 }
 else{
     $("#cams_submit").css("display", "none");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row form-group" id="cams_section">
                                <label class="col-md-5">
                                    <h5>Email ID<span class="form-required">*</span></h5>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-7" id="cams_e">
                                    <input type="email" name="cams_email" id="cams_email" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="cams_submit" style="display: none;">Submit Cams Data</button>
```